# Calculating heading of compass to a specific coordinate instead of to north

Tags: ios, algorithm, geolocation, ios6, mapkit

I can't get this algorithm right. I'm trying to make a compass that points at a certain location instead of just pointing to, let's say, north. Something is wrong. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, but i just can't find it. Any ideas?

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{

double distanceEast = (location.longitude > 0 && otherLocation.longitude < 0) ? 180 - location.longitude + otherLocation.longitude - -180: otherLocation.longitude - location.longitude;

    if (distanceEast < 0) {
        distanceEast += 360;
    }

    double distanceWest = (location.longitude < 0 && otherLocation.longitude > 0) ? -180 - location.longitude - 180 - otherLocation.longitude : location.longitude - otherLocation.longitude;

    if (distanceWest < 0) {
        distanceWest += 360;
    }

    float latitudinalDifference = (otherLocation.latitude - location.latitude);
    float longitudinalDifference = fmin(distanceEast,distanceWest);

    float arcTan = atan(longitudinalDifference / latitudinalDifference);

        float oldRadian = (-manager.heading.trueHeading *M_PI /180.0f)+arcTan+M_PI;
        float newRadian = (-newHeading.trueHeading *M_PI /180.0f)+arcTan+M_PI;

        CABasicAnimation *animation;
        animation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:oldRadian];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:newRadian];
        animation.duration = 0.5f;
        directionsArrow.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

        [directionsArrow.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotationCompass"];
        directionsArrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRadian);
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your entire fixed method? I would like to do this in my own app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double lon = location.longitude - otherLocation.longitude;
double y = sin(lon) * cos(otherLocation.latitude);
double x = cos(location.latitude) * sin(otherLocation.latitude) - sin(location.latitude) * cos(otherLocation.latitude) * cos(lon);
double angle = atan2(y, x);
```

`angle` is the bearing between the two locations.

Comment: I'm not sure how this fixes the problem. Can you elaborate the specific changes to the code? I want to do the same thing.

Comment: @AaronBratcher It's essentially what rob proposes in his answer. `x` and `y` are mercator coordinates. The angle (in radians) is calculated using `atan2`.

Answer (score 1):

[“Map Coordinates Systems” in the *Location Awareness Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW6) says “Specifically, on a Mercator map projection, a straight line drawn between any two points on the map yields a course heading that can be used in actual navigation on the surface of the Earth.”  This makes me think you should convert your map coordinates to map points (`MKMapPointForCoordinate`) and call `atan` on the difference between map points.  (Actually, you should probably use `atan2`, not `atan`.)  Have you tried that?