# GPS Heading - Compass Heading

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, heading, digital-compass

I have a dial with an arrow on it - I want this arrow to point to a GPS coordinate and adjusting for compass heading at the same time.

I'm getting the compass to rotate just fine, and I can also point the arrow in the correct GPS-heading, but I'm having trouble compensating for the compass heading when rotating the GPS-heading arrow.

Could anyone give me a quick example of this? Been struggling for days!

ATB.
Chris

Comment: And where exactly did you get stuck? Not much info in your question...

Comment: @rokjarc Updated with a bit more info

Comment: Some help is at this other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600648/calculating-heading-of-compass-to-a-specific-coordinate-instead-of-to-north